# Why does the IEnumerator not work? What can we do to make a delay in the firegun function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Our problem is that we are trying to make a delay in the FireGun function using IEnumerator, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is our PlayerControllerScript

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class PlayerController2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D playerrb;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    public float movespeed = 5;
    private Vector2 mousePosition;
    public Camera sceneCamera;
    public WeaponScript weaponscript;
    public int exp = 0;
    public int maxexp = 50;
    public bool newlevel = false;
    public bool gamepause = false;
    public bool doubleshot = false;
    public int life = 1;
    public Image heart;
    public int firegun = 1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerrb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        

    }
    public IEnumerator WaitASecond()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        
        // Code to execute after the delay
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && gamepause == false && doubleshot == false) 
        //{
        //    weaponscript.fireGun();
        //}
        //if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && gamepause == false && doubleshot == true)
        //{
        //    weaponscript.fireDoubleGun();
        //}

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
              StartCoroutine(WaitASecond());
              weaponscript.fireGun();
              StartCoroutine(WaitASecond());



        }

        if (exp == maxexp)
        {
            newlevel = true;
        }
        if (life == 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);

        }
        if (life == 2) {
            heart.gameObject.SetActive(true);   
        }
        if (life == 1) {
            heart.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Finds if they're pressing any of the moving buttons
        if (gamepause == false) {
            float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;
            // The mouse position allows the camera to find the mouse and it gives us where it is
            mousePosition = sceneCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            // This causes it to move. The normalized makes it so people won't go faster if they're doing diagonal
            playerrb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * movespeed, moveDirection.y * movespeed);
            Vector2 aimDirection = mousePosition - playerrb.position;
            //This makes it so the mouse's angle, and has  the player rotate towards that.
            float aimAngle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            playerrb.rotation = aimAngle;

        }

    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
               

        }
    }
   
}
```

Here is our Weapon Script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform firepoint;
    public float fireForce = 10.0f;
    public GameObject player;
    public PlayerController2 playercontroller;
    public void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        playercontroller = player.GetComponent<PlayerController2>();
    }

    public IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(bullet, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
       projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(firepoint.up * fireForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        
    }

    public void fireGun()
    {

        
        StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime());

    }

    public void fireDoubleGun()
    {

        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(bullet, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
        projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(firepoint.up * fireForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        GameObject projectile2 = Instantiate(bullet, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
        projectile2.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(firepoint.up * fireForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

I think the main problem with the code is somewhere in here, in our WeaponScript.

```
       public IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(bullet, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
       projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(firepoint.up * fireForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        
    }

    public void fireGun()
    {

        
        StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime());

    }
```

We have tried other ways of delaying the FireGun function, but they didn't work either.
The problem right now is that it keeps spawning endless amounts. Our goal is it to spawn a bullet every second.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't seem to work`? Is there no delay or does the projectile not spawn? or anything else?

Comment: @МаксимФисман There's no delay, it continues spawning them. I'll add that to my post.

Comment: Oh I see now. The problem is that the IEnumerator does not delay the whole program, it only adds a pause before the code that goes in itself. I'll post a full answer

Comment: You also wouldnt want a update loop that took 4s+ to run.

Comment: @BugFinder I don't think the delay works tho, because it keeps firing bullets instantly.

Comment: No because thats not how coroutines work they dont pause that code. However if they did your program they would freeze for 4s+ which no one wants either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your code is not where you expect it to be.

It is here:

```
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
              StartCoroutine(WaitASecond());
              weaponscript.fireGun();
              StartCoroutine(WaitASecond());
        }
```

You seem to think that the IEnumerators and Coroutines make a delay in the whole program.
Since your `WaitASecond()` function only includes one string with `WaitForSeconds`, it is obvious that you expect this piece of code function like the following:

1. A 1 second's delay
2. Fire
3. A 1 second's delay

However,  this is NOT how Coroutines work. A Coroutine does not delay the whole thread or program. It only delays its own code. So explain it, let's take your function `ExecuteAfterTime()` as an example:

```
       public IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(bullet, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
       projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(firepoint.up * fireForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        
    }
```

Here there WILL be a delay before instantiating a projectile, because this piece of code goes INSIDE the Coroutine and after the delay (`WaitForSeconds`). However, the outer code will keep working with no delays.

So, *back to the piece of code where the mistake lies*: in fact, it would work like this:

1. Starting a coroutine of 1 second's delay. The coroutine is now waiting, but the outer code keeps working.
2. Fire
3. Starting one more coroutine of 1 second's delay. The coroutine is now waiting, but the outer code keeps working.
   ---1 second later---
4. The first coroutine stops waiting and finishes, since it's over.
5. The second coroutine stops waiting and finished, since it's over.

I hope that you now understand what Coroutines are better.

---

As for the solution, I can suggest this:

```
    public IEnumerator FireCooldown()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f); // Wait 
        weaponsscripts.FireGun(); // we put shooting inside the coroutine, so it is subject to a delay now
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f); // You can add one more delay. Although I don't see any point in it, you do so in your code.
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
             StartCoroutine(FireCooldown()); // Starting a coroutine
        }
```

The function `FireCooldown()` here goes instead of your `ExecuteAfterTime()`

---

UPD: From the comments I understand that actually you do not need to shoot a projectile every frame. In this case let a Coroutine do all the work:

```
// This function starts the fire loop. Probably, it would be logical to call this function when a gun trigger gets pulled.
void StartFire() {
    StartCoroutine(FireLoop());
}

// This function shoots a projectile every n seconds
IEnumerator FireLoop() {
    while (true) { // Here you can put any condition
        weaponsscripts.FireGun(); // Shooting
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(n); // where n is the delay
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may have a variable `bool doShoot` and the Coroutine will be constantly either shooting or waiting:

```
IEnumerator FireLoop() {
    while(true) {
        if(doShoot) { // when a gun trigger is pulled, for example
            weaponsscripts.FireGun(); // Shooting
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(n); // where n is the delay
        }
        else yield return new WaitUntil(() => doShoot); // waiting until doShoot turns true
    }
}
```

In this case the Coroutine should be called somewhere in the beginning of the program, although I can't sure in this solution, since it's been long time I used Unity the last time...

Again, alternatively, you can get by without coroutines, using a cooldown variable. Every frame you'd decrease it: `cooldown -= Time.deltaTime` and check if a character should shoot, i.e. a gun trigger is pulled AND the cooldown <= 0. After the shot, the cooldown returns to its initial value

Comment: For me, even after I changed my code to the solution, it's still shooting out tons of bullets every second. Do I also need to change my firegun function?                                                 [ public void fireGun()
    {.            
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(bullet, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);                        
             projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(firepoint.up * fireForce,  ForceMode2D.Impulse);



    }]

Comment: Well, that is because you literally call the Coroutine function every single frame in the Update()! I thought that was on purpose. If you don't need a bullet a frame, what then? Shooting a bullet every n seconds?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for the confusion. I decided to put it in the Update, because I wanted the input getting to be instant, and I wasn't sure how else to do that.

Comment: @GeniusCoder I've updated my answer. Please, have a look, does it now match your aims?

Comment: For the first solution, the one with the fireloop, would we set the shoot to false after shooting one bullet in the weaponscript?

Comment: @GeniusCoder If you set it to false the fire will stop, while if you don't, it will keep shouting a bullet per every n seconds. So, my answer would be: it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerator` itself is a time-dependent method that can wait, so you can't expect the **Wait** working in the `Update` function. To solve the problem, pay attention to the code below.

```cs
public IEnumerator FireShot()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f); // this wait only work in local IEnumerator method
    
    weaponscript.fireGun(); // ...for example solution 1
}
```

---

But you need a delay dependent function, so create a float timer in the parameters and take the action in the second parameter.

```cs
using System;

...

public IEnumerator DoDelay(Action action, float delay = 0f) // This work with delay
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    action.Invoke();
}
```

```cs
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
{
    StartCoroutine(DoDelay(() => weaponscript.fireGun(), 1f)); // so FireGun or any method can invokes after defined delay time
}
```

Comment: For the Action action, that is creating an error message in my code.

Comment: @GeniusCoder `using System;`  write in the reference field. (see answer update)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but for  on the line for starting the DoDelay coroutine,  it says   Cannot Convert From Systems.Collection.Ienumerator to string

Comment: @GeniusCoder Email your original code to Kian.tianxuan@gmail.com.

Comment: I sent it to you

Comment: @GeniusCoder A parenthesis was in the wrong place. Take a look at the StartCoroutine section again. (updated Answer)

Comment: It still shoots constantly however.